# Breaking Substitution-Permutation cipher

Tags: cryptography

I have a ciphertext encrypted with a substitution-permutation cipher. I want to know how can I break this cipher and decrypt it into usual English text. 
**Here is the ciphertext:**
telipcs lp wwax drqx pzfq ii qpzprpr pd nic ephryxb ntrplx lcmxxrzd cx vmp qdpw. pd wvezm, zee ezxs mswe fn telipdcm xvq prpbx dw qmc rage pd nic uqjp xleses. brd cpwclx xa pcs degj epq ex mrfref nwnc xdz. msyx egd cpefx vaed zmcq qfcx wnp qcw cwy ya pcs dxrje. pq yfcwp tgze gew n yxavexqw, me mdcr prse meuwce! sl ld wvcrdyw, vctpb ere pdbzlfrw:

Comment: You need to perform frequency analysis.

Comment: Yeah but it won't work as 'e' and 'p' both have a maximum frequency of 28 in this ciphertext.

Comment: That is why Cryptoanalysis is not easy. You will need a little branching and you will be fine.

Comment: It is also possible that block substitution is involved in here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: @MartinParkin Questions asking “how do I decrypt this” are [explicitly off-topic on crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please do not vote to migrate to another site if you aren't familiar with its scope.